# On the low quality of larger font sizes

Tags: fontsize

I noticed the default font size 10 has a high quality meaning when we enlarge the resultant pdf we do not see the pixels. But unfortunately that is not the case for larger font sizes such as 12 and 20. Is there any way to make the quality of larger font sizes as high has that of the default size 10?
Below is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\newcommand{\twelve}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{12}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\twenty}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{ub}{n}\fontsize{20}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\begin{document}
{High-Q  Font 10}\\
{\twelve Low-Q  Font 12}\\
{\twenty Low-Q  Font 20}\\

\end{document}
```

Here is the resultant pdf 600%:
[image]

Comment: Install  the cm-super package.

Comment: Or, compile your test document with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Hi @Mico : LuaLatex gives us the same low quality for the large font sizes

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Is there an easy way to install cm-super package ? I read the documentation it is super overwhelming to move many many files.

Comment: if you are using a modern system like texlive 2021 or miktex you can install it with their package manager.

Comment: I use miktex, but not sure if I have cm-super, do you know if there is a way to check?

Comment: @Aria - Please see the answer I just posted.

Comment: If you installed a minimalist TeX distribution that doesn't come with a proper complement of vector fonts, the best remedy is to install a full TeX distribution.

Comment: How to install a full TeX distribution? (MikTex is better for me since I worked with it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

The default font family for LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX is Latin Modern, a clone of Computer Modern. They don't suffer from the pixellation issues you've encountered -- at least not if a full TeX  distribution, with all outline fonts installed, is in use.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\obeylines % just for this example
High Low Q 10
\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont
High Low Q 12
\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont
High Low Q 20
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico, why not instead of LuaLatex stay with Pdflatex and go from cmr to lmr? This is more preferable since there are some other applications that we get use to to the pdflatex, such as biber and bibliography,....

Comment: @Aria - One can use the `biblatex` package with pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, *and* XeLaTeX. `biber` is an external program and works just fine with inputs provided by pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, *and* XeLaTeX. I suggested using either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX as I (mis)understood the settings of your TeX distribution, as the example you provided appeared to suggest that your pdfLaTeX setup was somehow tied to the use of raster fonts, and that using vector fonts (aka outline fonts) was somehow not an option for your when using pdfLaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question base on the fundamental hint from Mico:
The problem is cmr=Computer Modern (default) font family giving us a low quality for larger font sizes running by pdfLaTex in the resultant pdf file.
Mico suggested an easy way to fix this: using lmr=Latin Modern font family, and then no need to go with LuaLaTeX just stay with pdfLaTex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\newcommand{\twelve}{\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{12}{\baselineskip} 
\selectfont}
\newcommand{\twenty}{\usefont{T1}{lmr}{ub}{n}\fontsize{20}{\baselineskip} 
\selectfont}
\begin{document}
{High-Q  Font 10}\\
{\twelve Low-Q  Font 12}\\
{\twenty Low-Q  Font 20}\\

\end{document}
```

Below is the High Quality pdf result for all font sizes :)
[image]